# amplify project will not build within amplify console

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

Everything builds and runs successfully when running locally, but as soon as I try to auto build and deploy through the AWS Amplify Console, i get the following error in the "frontend" build log.

```
                                                                  # Executing command: npm run build
2020-02-29T22:35:39.451Z [INFO]: > aws-amplify-angular@4.1.7 build /codebuild/output/src700601921/src/webApp/node_modules/aws-amplify-angular
                                 > npm run transpile && npm run package && npm run minify && npm run declarations
2020-02-29T22:35:39.678Z [INFO]: > aws-amplify-angular@4.1.7 transpile /codebuild/output/src700601921/src/webApp/node_modules/aws-amplify-angular
                                 > ngc
2020-02-29T22:35:45.984Z [WARNING]: src/components/authenticator/authenticator/authenticator.factory.ts(44,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/authenticator/confirm-sign-in-component/confirm-sign-in.factory.ts(43,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/authenticator/confirm-sign-up-component/confirm-sign-up.factory.ts(44,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/authenticator/sign-in-component/sign-in.component.factory.ts(45,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/authenticator/sign-up-component/sign-up.factory.ts(45,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/authenticator/require-new-password-component/require-new-password.factory.ts(43,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/authenticator/greeting-component/greeting.factory.ts(44,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/authenticator/forgot-password-component/forgot-password.factory.ts(44,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/storage/s3-album-component/s3-album.factory.ts(45,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/storage/s3-image-component/s3-image.factory.ts(46,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/storage/photo-picker-component/photo-picker.factory.ts(51,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/interactions/chatbot/chatbot.factory.ts(51,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
                                    src/components/xr/sumerian-scene-component/sumerian-scene.factory.ts(37,3): error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
2020-02-29T22:35:46.012Z [WARNING]: npm
2020-02-29T22:35:46.014Z [WARNING]: ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
                                    npm ERR! errno 1
                                    npm ERR! aws-amplify-angular@4.1.7 transpile: `ngc`
                                    npm ERR! Exit status 1
                                    npm
2020-02-29T22:35:46.015Z [WARNING]: ERR!
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if you run 'ng build --prod'  or 'npm run build'?

Answer (score 0):

How does your build yaml file looks like?
I can remember of a similiar problem, which was solved through a `amplify push --simple` in the backend section.

[amplify.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4rUe.png)